# White screen using Phaser v3 in Ionic framework

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, phaser-framework

I tried to create a Phaser game watching this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W43SoPeNctQ

The problem is that when the page reloads I see the canvas a few milliseconds and this one desapears to let place to a white screen; I only see header bar on top and tabs on bottom of the screen.

There's no errors in the console.

I'm using Phaser v3.24.1, like in the video, and the browser is Brave, so Chromium.

"ionic info" shows this :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.10
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.10
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.7
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.7

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.10
   OS     : Windows 10
```

and "ng version" shows this :

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.10
Node: 14.15.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.11
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.10
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.10
@angular/cli                    11.2.10
@schematics/angular             11.2.10
@schematics/update              0.1102.10
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.7
```

Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : the call at the phaser initialisation method needs to be placed in ionViewDidEnter() and not in the constructor like I did.

Comment: Had the same problem with Ionic/Vue and Phaser. Thanks for the answer!